# Spring Integration JDBC Poller. Update with compound Primary Key

Tags: spring-integration

I am using a JDBC poller to process some db records and when the workflow is finished, i need to update those records. I could not find a way to make if work for tables with compound keys.

This is my example. Table EVENTS. with primary key (DATETIME, EVENT_LOCATION, EVENT_TYPE). I cannot change the schema.

Rows are mapped into a POJO with the property names: dateTime, location, type.

```xml
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    query="select * from events where uploaded = 0”
    channel="fromdb" data-source="dataSource"
    max-rows="${app.maxrows}"
    row-mapper=“eventRowMapper”
    update="update events set uploaded=1 where DATETIME =:dateTime AND EVENT_LOCATION=:location AND EVENT_TYPE = :type”>
<int:poller fixed-delay="${app.intervalmsecs}" />
```

But I get a syntax error response from the server when the poller tries to update those records.

After reading the docs, it seems that the poller uses ´(:id)´ to update the rows , but it assumes a single-column PK. I could not find any information about updating rows with multiple columns in the primary key

Is there any way to update rows with multiple column Primary Key? Or should i use an outbound jdbc or code my own update solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the complete stack trace; your Event object and row mapper; I just changed one of the tests from

```
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(embeddedDatabase,
            "select * from item where id not in (select id from copy)");
    adapter.setUpdateSql("insert into copy values(:id,10)");
```

to

```
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(embeddedDatabase,
            "select * from item where id not in (select foo from copy)");
    adapter.setUpdateSql("insert into copy values(:foo,:status)");
```

and it worked just fine.

As long as the column appears as a property of the result of the select query it will work. (The result being the object created by the rowmapper).

i.e. `dateTime`, `location` and `type` must be properties on `Event`.

Also, based on your `update-query`, it looks like you should have `update-per-row` set to true since it only updates one row.

Comment: `update-per-row` did the trick!! I was focused on the compound PK and did not pay attention to that. If i set it to `true`, it works. Thanks!